# Запятая перед причастным оборотом, выступающим в роли определения

Tags: пунктуация

В какие отношения здесь вступают определения "одну" и "много раз и многими заявленную" и, соответственно, нужна ли между ними запятая (запятые)?

Процитируем еще одну много раз и многими заявленную декларацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна, если речь идёт о единственной декларации: она сделает уточнением определительный оборот  "много раз и многими заявленную". Если же запятой не ставить, из предложения будет следовать, что перед этим уже цитировались декларации с такой же предысторией, и эта - ещё одна в их ряду. Второй запятой здесь не нужно, поскольку оборот предшествует определяемому существительному, а обстоятельственные признаки (многими, много раз) не несут самостоятельного смысла, лишь конкретизируя определение (она как бы "многозаявленная").